# Missing dependency target "<PBXTargetDependency:0x201d16ca0:<no cached name>>"

Tags: objective-c, ios-4.2, xcode4

I keep on getting this warning in my Xcode IDE:

> Missing dependency target "<PBXTargetDependency:0x201d16ca0:<no cached name>>"

What the heck does that mean?

Comment: Me too. Very annoying if you ask me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This means that in the **project.pbxproj** file inside of *yourproject*.xcodeproj bundle one or more **PBXTargetDependency** definitions have to be removed.
After removing the entries the warnings won't be shown anymore. This issue is an Xcode- and not a project-related one, thus I've filed a bug in the bugreporter (https://bugreport.apple.com/).

Answer (score 3):

OK i got it , basically you need to go to the project.proj file and find a string that mentions that. Thats how you fix it

Comment: Can you elaborate more on that statement. Since I am very interested in the answer. That warning really drives me crazy.

Comment: I get all kinds of errors in XCode 4, crashes all the time, and this error as well.

Comment: Basically I had the same problem. Open the mentioned file and simply delete all "PBXTargetDependency" lines. Then you'll find a 'BEGIN PBXTargetDependency Section'. Delete the whole section. Now go back to the project and re-add any dependency you may have and this will completely solve your problem. I had this for over 6 months and Apple's bug reporting didn't do anything. They simply said it's not their problem and they can't find an issue with xcode. So I had to figure it out myself.

Comment: OMG!  Following this advice fixed several problems I've been having with Xcode for years: constant crashes daily, crashing every time I try to add a file, modify a filename, update the project file.  Awesome.